# How to wildcard numbers to a certain length in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a column in a table that stores every number combination up to 6 digits followed by .lyr

Eg, 0.lyr ,1.lyr, 00.lyr, 11.lyr - 999999.lyr

I want to be able to write a query that shows me all 4 digit combinations: 0000.lyr-9999.lyr. Is there anything I can do without needing to use an in-statement?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourcolumn REGEXP '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`   (When you need to check for the existence of `.lyr` too, you can add that to the regular expression.)

Comment: What is your DBMS product? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: I am using mode, which is is mySQL! Sorry, I should have added that

Comment: Never too late to do it, so I just added the tag `mysql`

Comment: Thanks Luuk! This one is a struggle, would be much easier if I needed 0.lyr-9999.lyr instead of 0000.lyr-9999.lyr

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your value to numeric one and check.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE 0 + columnname BETWEEN 0 AND 9999;
```

If `0.lyr` and `0000.lyr` are different values and you need only the row with 2nd value then use rregular expression check.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE columnname REGEXP '^\\d{4}.lyr$';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JG0UPENa)